# How are these two terms in $y$ removed from the triple integral? (Divergence theorem?)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I will post the photo here for convenience sake. I wish to understand why it just says, odd in $y$ and then cancels the $y$ bits and simplifies the integral a whole lot.

Here is the scan: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2kcK.png

The part in pink is the bit I am referring to. I tried looking at it but i just can't see why they would just cancel like that.

Answer (score 1):

First it would be good to rewrite your complete question rather than just post a photo!

Then the answer is just that if you have an odd function $f$ and $a \in \mathbb R$ $$\int_{-a}^a f(t) dt=0$$

Comment: Okay. But why would expressions with other terms than $y$ necessarily cancel then? How do we know to integrate these with respect to $y$ because if we integrated with respect to another variable first then the symmetry would be lost wouldn't it?

Comment: By Fubini theorem, if a double integral exists, it's value is independent of the order of computation with the different variables. So what you mention can't happen.